# C# - Type Parameters in Constructor - No Generics

Tags: c#, type-parameter

I have a class that I am trying to do unit tests on.  The class is a WCF Service Class.  (Making it a generics class is not my goal.)

I have a data access layer (DAL) type (called UserDAL) that is instantiated in many methods.  To get these methods under test, I need to get this local variables mocked.  (Each instance of UserDAL has method specific value in it, so changing it a class level variable would result in messy code, so I would rather not do that.)

What I am thinking would be nice is to overload the constructor and pass in a type to use in the local methods.  The empty param constructor would still create a normal UserDAL, but the overloaded one would have a mock type that implements IUserDAL.

I am not sure of the syntax to say I want to pass in a type.  Note that I am not trying to pass in a variable, but a type.

Example:

```
public class MyWCFClass: IMyWCFClass
{
    private TypeParam _myUserDALType;
    public MyWCFClass()
    {
        _myUserDALType = UserDAL;
    }
    public MyWCFClass(TypeParam myUserDALType)
    {
        _myUserDALType = myUserDALType;
    }

    //methods to use it
    public MyMethod()
    {
        IUserDAL userDAL = new _myUserDALType();
        //Call method in IUserDAL
        userDAL.CreateUser();
    }


    // Several similar methods that all need a different UserDAL go here
    .....
}
```

So, I don't know what kind of type TypeParam is (I made that up) or if this kind of think is even possible.

If you have a non generics solution that would be great.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do Generics is because all static method calls have to be updated to use the generic param (ie MyWCFClass<UserDAL>.MyStaticMethod)  This requires references to my Data access layer in projects that should not know about the data access layer.  (Plus I tried it and I got an Object not set to an isntance of an object error.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean `Type`, using `Activator.CreateInstance` to create instances:

```
public class MyWCFClass: IMyWCFClass
{
    private Type _myUserDALType;
    public MyWCFClass()
    {
        _myUserDALType = typeof(UserDAL);
    }
    public MyWCFClass(Type myUserDALType)
    {
        _myUserDALType = myUserDALType;
    }

    //methods to use it
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        IUserDAL userDAL = (IUserDAL) Activator.CreateInstance(_myUserDALType );
        //Call method in IUserDAL
        userDAL.CreateUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this solution is exactly what Vaccano asked for I encourage the solution Chris and JS Bangs suggested: use InversionOfControl and a Container (Spring.Net, Ninject, Structuremaps, Unity, LinFu, you name it...) as well as ctor-injection. Also  in the above solution there will be exceptions thrown during runtime if _myUserDALType hasn't got a default ctor.

Comment: The problem with those patterns is that they kind of assume that the variable is a class level variable.  What I am working with is a type that is instantiated in serveral methods locally.  (See my question about that.)  If I could move it to a single class level variable, then all those Ideas (and others) would work great!

Comment: I'd raise the question, why is it instantiated in these methods locally? That seems broken/wrong to me, and is almost trivial to correct. If your DAL is essentially worthless after use because it is mutated, take a constructor with IUserDalFactory instead, with one method Create.

Comment: Booja!!!  That is a Great Idea!  I am going to try that out and see if it works out!

I Voted up your answer to this question (and a several others) to "pay" for your great advice.  (I would set it as the answer, but it as you stated, Marc's answer was exactly what I had asked for.)

Comment: JasonTrue, That worked out Great!  Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 8):

What you are really looking for is Dependency Injection, but you can do this by passing in a Type argument and then using Activator.CreateInstance(Type) to create the object when you need it.

As far as doing real DI (which will make doing this testing a lot easier), I know that [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/) works reasonable well.

Answer (score 5):

Use a Type, and use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate it:

```
private Type _myUserDALType;

IUserDAL userDAL = Activator.CreateInstance(_myUserDALType) as IUserDAL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your real problem is not in the generics or lack thereof. Your real problem is that `MyWFCClass` is calling both `new` and the method. As per [Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/), you get the best testability by separating classes that call `new` from classes that implement logic. Instead of having `MyWFCClass` somehow know the type that you want to implement and using reflection, just pass the `IUserDal` object to the constructor, allowing the test harness to pass in a mock object when needed.

If, for some reason, you can't do this and you can't use generics, then you have to do it yourself. Pass a `Type` object to the `MyWFCClass` constructor, then use reflection to find and invoke the constructor you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass in a type, you can use the Type object:

```
public class A
{
  public A(Type classType)
  {
    object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(...classType...);
  }
}

public class B
{
...
}

public class C
{
  public static void main(string[] args)
  {
    A a = new A(typeof(B));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If `IUserDAL` defines the interface that your WCF service needs to get its job done, why not just take an instance of it as a constructor parameter? And since WCF requires a default constructor, why not have that default constructor call your parameterized constructor with a default implementation?

```
public class MyWCFClass : IMyWCFClass
{
    private readonly IUserDAL _userDAL;

    public MyWCFClass()
        : this(new DefaultUserDAL())
    {
    }

    public MyWCFClass(IUserDAL userDAL)
    {
        _userDAL = userDAL;
    }
}
```

If you're using a dependency injection container, you could expose it as a singleton and satisfy the parameterized constructor by using that singleton:

```
public MyWCFClass()
    this(Container.Instance.Resolve<IUserDAL>())
{
}
```

With this approach, your WCF class has everything it needs to get its job done, but it is still unit-testable. Moreover, it is not responsible for creating its dependencies, which is a good thing.

Comment: "Moreover, it is not responsible for creating its dependencies, which is a good thing." But now it has a direct dependency on infrastructure and violates the "Container Ignorance" best practice, imho.

Comment: If WCF provides a hook that you can use to create the service objects, then you could hook into that. Otherwise, I see this as the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 1):

Far simpler, and more consistent with other applications that have this problem, would be to extract an interface on UserDal, then you would have something more like:

```
public MyWCFClass() : this(new UserDAL())
{
}
public MyWCFClass(IUserDal userDAL)
{
    _myUserDAL = myUserDAL;
}
```

This is also easier to use with dependency-injection frameworks than your proposed method, though that's certainly a secondary concern

(Edited to clarify an alternative solution based on other comments)

If your DAL is essentially worthless after use because it is mutated, take a constructor with IUserDalFactory instead, with one method `Create()`.

Comment: Alas this assumes that _myUserDAL can be a class level object.  They way I have it currently structured that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there is a type called "Type".  With it you can create a parameter and pass in any valid type.

```
private void MyMethod(Type myType)
{
  //Do something
}
```